# SQL query for fetching the total of price for last entered date using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using php. I want to fetch the total price for last entered date using query.I used a join query for joining 3 tables.In the first table user details are stored oc_user,2nd table(oc_postable) contain the invoice number and refid for product(the products entered togehther have same invoice number and refid),3rd table(oc_addcart) contain each product detail,price,refid,userid,date.I used the following query

```
SELECT a.userid,FROM_UNIXTIME(max(a.addedtime)) as addedtime,sum(price) as totalamnt from `oc_addtocart` a,`oc_postable` b,`oc_user` as c where a.status=1 and c.user_id=a.userid AND b.`ticketrefid` = a.refid group by a.refid ORDER BY c.user_id ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

I got the Output as

```
userid  addedtime   totalamnt
1   2015-04-24 10:40:56     679.99
1   2015-05-07 15:30:44     2700
1   2015-04-24 11:00:08     100
1   2015-05-07 14:55:05     400
1   2015-04-24 09:24:35     230
1   2015-05-07 15:01:59     679.99
5   2015-05-08 12:19:41     430
```

I want to get the output as

```
userid  addedtime   totalamnt
 1  2015-05-07 15:30:44     2700
 5  2015-05-08 12:19:41     430
```

oc_user table struture

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

oc_postable table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_postable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `table_status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_designator` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `table_position` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ticketrefid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `split_no` int(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user` int(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `payment_method` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

oc_addcart table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_addtocart` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `prodid` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `options_selected` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `notes` longtext NOT NULL,
  `status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `addedtime` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `refid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `togo` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;
```

please suggest a solution.Waiting for your reply.

Comment: You should add the table structure.

Comment: hint: sum amount, max date group by user

Comment: SELECT a.userid,sum(price) as totalamnt,max(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.addedtime)) as addedtime from `oc_addtocart` a,`oc_postable` b,`oc_user` as c where a.status=1 and c.user_id=a.userid AND b.`ticketrefid` = a.refid group by a.userid ORDER BY c.user_id ASC LIMIT 0,20 this query return the toalsum of all dates,not the total of that particular date.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT A.USERID, A.ADDEDTIME AS ADDEDTIME, A.PRICE AS TOTALAMT 
FROM OC_ADDTOCART A 
INNER JOIN OC_USER C ON A.USERID = C.USER_ID
INNER JOIN OC_POSTABLE B ON A.REFID = B.TICKETREFID
WHERE A.STATUS =1
AND A.ADDEDTIME = 
(SELECT MAX(ADDEDTIME) ADT FROM OC_ADDTOCART WHERE USERID = A.USERID) 
ORDER BY C.USER_ID ASC LIMIT 0,20`
```